# Internet can't be connected - "Disconnected - you are now offline"

Tags: networking, internet

I am a very new user of Ubuntu and booted my Lenovo 3000 n500 laptop with Ubuntu 14.04.4. Every time it's displaying "disconnected - you are offline". But the same file is used for my friend's PC and that is flawless.

Comment: What're you trying to do? Are you trying to access some shared file? Does the disconnect happen on its own, or when you're doing something? What connection method are you using?

Comment: Actually I was using win 7 and after that I have booted it with Ubuntu 14.04.4LTS and at the time of start up it displays a message"Disconnected-you are now offline". And I can't connect to the web .I use Wifi connection. Thank you.

Comment: So, did you create the WiFi connection with NetworkManager? What happens when you try to activate it?

Comment: There was no wireless options.....it was only showing wired connections--thanku

Comment: Enter in terminal `ifconfig | grep wlan`. If it wouldn't print anything, then you most probably need to install WiFi drivers. Search in the system settings for something, like «Additional drivers». Or you can enter in terminal `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`, it would list devices which needs *(or may need — as in the case of GPU, which would have drivers in use, but may also have alternative ones)* drivers, and the drivers package names after the words `drivers: `.

Comment: Thank u but i have rebooted it with ubuntu 12.04 LTS and now i can connect to the internet. But now the Gcc compiler is not working properly....Thank u so much....

Comment: Okay, reposted as an answer. I have no idea what could happen with gcc *(because you didn't say the details ☺)*, but perhaps you didn't install *g++*? I mean, to compile C++ code *(i.e. not C)* you need *g++*, which is missing by default.

Comment: actually i have written a code in.....i have used #include<math.h>.....but still it cant recognize 'pow' command.....and for c++ from where i should install g++?? pls help....thamk you

Comment: To install *g++* enter in terminal `sudo apt-get install g++` *(also you can, of course, search in applications list a GUI for that, it would probably signed something like «Installing applications»; I'm not sure of exact wording because I'm using KDE, not Unity)*. As for the code, I think the problem in the code itself. You can check by compiling `#include <math.h>
int main(){pow(1,2);}` *(enter newline between `> int`, newlines in comments are removed)*, if it would get compiled — it does for me — then you have an error in your code.

Comment: there is no problem in the code....as it is running in Dev cpp......i have included #include <math.h> still pow is not identified

Comment: Well, then I think you're better asking a separate question with all the relevant details, like the code you're trying to compile, the IDE you're using, the exact error(s).

Comment: ok at first i am posting the compilation error pls help....thanx

Comment: abhishek@abhishek-Lenovo-3000-N500:~$ gcc bhat.c
bhat.c: In function ‘main’:
bhat.c:47:2: warning: unknown conversion type character 0x9 in format [-Wformat]
bhat.c:47:2: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘(’ in format [-Wformat]
/tmp/cczJaVDa.o: In function `f':
bhat.c:(.text+0x68b): undefined reference to `pow'
/tmp/cczJaVDa.o: In function `err':
bhat.c:(.text+0x6c5): undefined reference to `pow'
bhat.c:(.text+0x6fc): undefined reference to `pow'
bhat.c:(.text+0x71a): undefined reference to `pow'
bhat.c:(.text+0x751): undefined reference to `pow'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: When I said about a new question, I mean a new question with all the details, but not a screwed by comment formatting text. FWIW, I think if you add `-lm` to the command line, like `gcc bhat.c -lm`, it would fix the problem.

Comment: Thanx a lot...actually i cant understand the compilation error

Answer (score 0):

Enter in terminal `ifconfig | grep ^wl`. If it wouldn't print anything, then you most probably need to install WiFi drivers.

Search in the system settings for something like “Additional drivers”. Or you can enter in terminal `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`, it would list devices which needs *(or may need — as in the case of GPU, which would have drivers in use, but may also have alternative ones)* drivers, and the drivers package names after the words `drivers:` .